# How to skip intermediate nodes in Latex tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I have the following LaTeX code for a timeline (using `tree`), but I'd like the two empty boxes following the "no" box to disappear, and instead to just have a straight arrow to action3 -- something like this:

```
yes -> action1 -> action2 -> action3
no  -----------------------> action3
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=.65]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
        {thick, draw, -latex,
            edge from parent fork right},
            every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=0.7in,text width=0.7in, align=center},grow'=right}
\Tree
    [. {do?}
            [. {yes }
                [. {action1}
                   [. {action2}
                      [. {action3}
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
            ]
            [. {no }
               [. {}
                 [. {}
                   [. {action3}
                   ]
                 ]
                ]
            ]
    ]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `tikz-qtree`, you can remove edges using `\edge[draw=none];` and later connect the `no`-node and the `action3`-node with `\draw`.

```
\Tree
    [. {do?}
            [. {yes }
                [. {action1}
                   [. {action2}
                      [. {action3}
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
            ]
            [.\node(no){no}; \edge[draw=none];
               [ \edge[draw=none];
                 [ \edge[draw=none];
                   [.\node(a3){action3};
                   ]
                 ]
                ]
            ]
    ]
\draw[-latex] (no)--(a3);
```

[image]

Comment: It is always better to post a complete example. Could you make this compilable?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, both. Here is the solution I came up with after posting the question: 
(Note, the code also moves the yes and no to above the arrows)
(Also note the \edge[-] command to avoid the additional intermediate arrow ends)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5in,sibling distance=.25in,scale=.65]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={thick, draw, -latex, edge from parent fork right},
     every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=0.7in,minimum height=0.65in,text width=0.7in, align=center},grow'=right}
\Tree
[. \node {do?};
    \edge node[above, pos=0.7] {yes};
    [. {action1}
        [. {action2}
            [. {action3} ]
        ]
    ]
    \edge[-] node[below, pos=0.6] {no};
    [
     \edge[-] {};
        [
         \edge {};
            [. {action3} ]
        ]
     ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Commenting `. {}` twice:

```latex
\Tree
    [. {do?}
            [. {yes }
                [. {action1}
                   [. {action2}
                      [. {action3}
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
            ]
            [. {no }
               [ %. {}
                 [ %. {}
                   [. {action3}
                   ]
                 ]
                ]
            ]
    ]
```

you get:

[image: screenshot of output]

This should be further improved removing the two arrow tips (and I guess this would require some deeper change in the code).

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of **forest** is that you can use `tier` to tell the package that certain nodes should be on the same level of the tree, even if some have more intervening nodes than others.

For example, in the code below

```
    if n children=0{tier=terminums}{},
```

says that terminal nodes should all be placed on the same tier of the tree. So the 2 action 3 nodes can be placed without needing to create dummy nodes for the one with fewer ancestors.

A style `label me={}{}` is created for convenient placement of the `yes` and `no` labels on the edges. The first argument is added to the label node's options and can be used to specify a relative position e.g. `above right` or an anchor e.g. `anchor=north west` or whatever. The second argument gives the content of the label.

The big advantage of the package is that, once you've configured a style, you can specify trees very concisely. For example:

```
  [do?
    [action 1, label me={above, anchor=south west}{yes}
      [action 2
        [action 3]
      ]
    ]
    [action 3, label me={below, anchor=north west}{no}]
  ]
```

produces

[image: action chains]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  label me/.style n args=2{
    delay={edge label/.wrap value={node [midway, #1, font=\scriptsize] {#2}}}
  },
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    text width=15mm,
    minimum height=7mm,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge={->},
    text centered,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(3mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    if n children=0{tier=terminums}{},
    l sep+=5mm,
  }
  [do?
    [action 1, label me={above, anchor=south west}{yes}
      [action 2
        [action 3]
      ]
    ]
    [action 3, label me={below, anchor=north west}{no}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```